# Replace 0 with blanks in replace statement with nested isnull

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working a query where I am comparing one value which is a series of concatenated fields to confirm the specific fields which are to be used within the value.

I have written a script to check this

```
   SELECT TOP 100
  [Opportunity Id]
  , replace(cast(isnull([country],'-') as varchar) 
  + cast(isnull([[Column 2],'-') as varchar) 
  + cast(isnull([[Column 3],'-') as varchar) 
  + cast(isnull([[Column 4],'-') as varchar) 
  + left(convert(varchar, isnull([Column 5],' '),120),10),'-','')

      FROM [Table]
     where [Opportunity Id] != replace(cast(isnull([country],'-') as varchar) 
  + cast(isnull([Column 2],'-') as varchar) 
  + cast(isnull([Column 3],'-') as varchar) 
  + cast(isnull([Column 4],'-') as varchar) 
  + left(convert(varchar, isnull([Column 5],' '),120),10),'-','')
```

When replacing the country value I am often left with 0 instead of a blank as is intended. Is there any way to prevent this?

An example of the dataset returned is

```
 0123456
 0234567
 0345678
 0456789
 0567890
```

where as the desired data set is

```
     123456
     234567
     345678
     456789
     567890
```

I am putting in the hyphen in order to replace blanks and one of the fields being concatenated is a date which needs its hyphen removed so I am using it as a default to mark values to be removed.

Comment: Is it because Country can be 0? Because then you could change your ISNULL to `ISNULL(NULLIF([country], 0), '-')`

Comment: Show sample data and the results you are getting.  Also, never use `varchar` in SQL Server without a length.  You should replace all such occurrences with something like `varchar(255)`.

Comment: Why do you put in '-' just to replace it with ''

Comment: Use a CTE and you won't need to repeat the big expression - With DataSet as
(
SELECT [Opportunity Id], (big expression) AS JoinedFields
FROM [grip_dq].[grip_t].[grip_trades]
)
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM DataSet WHERE [Opportunity Id] != JoinedFields

Comment: As @GordonLinoff suggested, show some sample data. Ideally, go to SQLFiddle.com and create a sample that shows us the behavior. Then post the link to the fiddle here.